# Using an email address as the unique identifier instead of username with Shiro for Grails

Tags: authentication, grails, shiro

I'm looking to move from using a username / password combination for authentication in my Grails app to using email / password. I have attempted to make the changes to the AuthControler.groovy and ShiroDbReal.groovy to allow this but it doesn't allow me to login.

Here is my model class

```
class User {
String email
String passwordHash
byte[] passwordSalt


static belongsTo = Account
static hasMany = [ roles: Role, permissions: String ]

static constraints = {
    email (nullable: false, blank: false, unique: true)
}
}
```

Here is my AuthController signIn function

```
def signIn = {
    def authToken = new UsernamePasswordToken(params.email, params.password as String)

    if (params.rememberMe) {
        authToken.rememberMe = true
    }

    def targetUri = params.targetUri ?: "/"

    def savedRequest = WebUtils.getSavedRequest(request)
    if (savedRequest) {
        targetUri = savedRequest.requestURI - request.contextPath
        if (savedRequest.queryString) targetUri = targetUri + '?' + savedRequest.queryString
    }

    try{
        SecurityUtils.subject.login(authToken)
        redirect(uri: targetUri)
    }
    catch (AuthenticationException ex){
        log.info "Authentication failure for user '${params.username}'."
        flash.message = message(code: "login.failed")
        redirect(action: "login", params: m)
    }
}
```

Finally my ShiroDbReal.groovy

```
    def authenticate(authToken) {
    log.info "Attempting to authenticate ${authToken.username} in DB realm..."
    def email = authToken.username

    if (email == null) {
        throw new AccountException("Null usernames are not allowed by this realm.")
    }

    def user = User.findByEmail(email)
    if (!user) {
        throw new UnknownAccountException("No account found for user [${username}]")
    }

    log.info "Found user '${user.username}' in DB"
    def account = new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(email, user.passwordHash, new SimpleByteSource(user.passwordSalt), "ShiroDbRealm")

    if (!credentialMatcher.doCredentialsMatch(authToken, account)) {
        log.info "Invalid password (DB realm)"
        throw new IncorrectCredentialsException("Invalid password for user '${username}'")
    }

    return account
}
```

I'm recieving a 'groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: username for class: icango.User' exception in the debugger at the 'SecurityUtils.subject.login(authToken)' method call.

I'm not really sure where else to look because I can't find any documentation about changing the unique identifier. Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to change the following line:

```
log.info "Found user '${user.username}' in DB"
```

Remove it or change it to :

```
log.info "Found user '${user.email}' in DB"
```

should fix it.

Comment: Because logging was turned off I didn't think these statements would get evaluated, I was wrong. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

The same goes for all your exceptions by the way ...  You should change all username occurences to email.